# Best pattern for handling Orchestrate.io queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code in my Node/Express project

```
exports.getProductById = function(req, res){
  db.get('product', req.params.id).then(function(res2){
    res.render('product/get', {title:'Product', product:res2.body, categories: db.categories});
  })
  .fail(function (err) {
    res.redirect('/');
  })
}
```

This works but it seems like it could be a lot better, however, my lack of Javascript experience seems to be an issue. I would envision something like this...

```
var callback = function(res2){
  res.render('product/get', {title:'Product', product:res2.body, categories: db.categories});
}
var errorCallback = function (err) {
    res.redirect('/');
}
exports.getProductById = function(req, res){
  db.get('product', req.params.id).then(callback)
  .fail(errorCallback)
}
```

Of course the problem here is I have no idea how to pass the res object to the Callback. What is the best pattern for handling this type of scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I wrote the orchestrate.io client library for JavaScript, and your first run through is actually good. I think you'll find it easier to keep `req` and `res` within the `getProductById` function. If you wish to avoid clutter, you can write additional functions that handle the data, format it, etc. and return back those changes to `getProductById`. This will make it easier to keep track of what is going on.

Comment: Ok I was just trying to make my main routes classes a little cleaner but shouldn't (or can't) be done is good enough for me.

Comment: @Jackie it is possible. You can use `.call` or `.apply` on `callback` and `errorCallback` to pass more arguments.

My hesitance is that your code will end up more obfuscated (in my opinion).